# How to read jpeg image using C in 2D Array

Tags: arrays, image, jpeg, ocr

Hello i'm working on project that convert image to text [OCR] but my doctor asked for manual algorithm so i can't use opencv or something like that but any suggestion will be great too for OCR in C ! and now i'm trying to read a jpeg using C language and convert that image to 2D Array like this one :

```
int A[10][10] ={
                {250,249,222,233,244,20,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,19,20,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,18,244,19,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,17,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,18,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,10,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,20,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,19,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,20,244,244,244,244},
                {250,249,222,233,244,18,244,244,244,244},
               };
```

but the 10x10 will depend on the height and the width of the image 
i tried alot of libraries GDAL, Jpeglib ..etc but nothing worked 
i finished my code on the above matrix but now it must load an image from desktop for example or any directory and convert it to matrix like the above one :).

I'm really appreciate any help u can do :)

Answer (score 0):

A. What are you trying to load into the array?

Is your image grayscale with only one component? Or is it three component color? A color image needs a 3D array.

B. The complexity of JPEG is such that, unless you want to spend months writing a decoder, you are going to have to get a library working somehow. You might want to seek help getting an existing decoder to work with your application.